In embeds.0.description: This field is required
я загружаю правила из json, и потом отправляю в канал, получая его своей функцией:
@commands.slash_command(name='правила', description='отправляет правила')
@commands.is_owner()
async def json(ctx):
    with open('./cogs/rules.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        await channel('rul').send(embed=disnake.Embed.from_dict(load(f)))

но выдаёт ошибку:
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embeds.0.description: This field is required

свой json с правилами без необходимости я пока что раскрывать не буду, но я его достал из https://message.style, возможно это из-за того, в нём есть json кнопок
{
  "content": "**Находиться здесь — это привилегия не всем доступная, а не право. Соблюдайте правила сервера и [Discord ToS](https://discord.com/terms), не грубите другим участникам и не создавайте проблем, которых можно избежать.**",
  "tts": false,
  "embeds": [
    {
      "id": 134701460,
      "description": "**1.** - dfg\- ndfg\n- asd",
      "fields": [],
      "title": "**Наказания**"
    },
    {
      "id": 743241642,
      "description": "**1.** - asd\n- asd\n- asd",
      "fields": [],
      "title": "**Общие правила для всех участников**"
    },
    {
      "id": 13533701,
      "description": "- Участниками считаются только те, у кого есть роль <@&1289473989084708888>.\n- Я(<@995232204932264006>) не несу ответственность за действия кого-либо на сервере.\n- Можно подать аппеляцию/обжаловать наказание через сообщение в личку от <@1265980222726082570> после получения наказания.",
      "fields": [],
      "title": "**ВАЖНО**"
    }
  ],
  "components": [
    {
      "id": 540754150,
      "type": 1,
      "components": [
        {
          "id": 914294181,
          "type": 2,
          "style": 3,
          "label": "✅ Согласиться с правилами",
          "action_set_id": "440616215"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": {
    "440616215": {
      "actions": [
        {
          "type": 3,
          "id": 56570936,
          "target_id": "1289473989084708888",
          "public": false,
          "disable_default_response": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


Так проблема именно в json, его нужно в вопрос добавить. Данные из него грузятся, и на них ругается, что нет обязательного поля description.

в какой вопрос добавить?

В ваш вопрос добавить, в какой же еще. Нажмите [edit] под вопросом и добавьте туда.

добавил json, я немного правила сами убрал вместо них похожее но с наборо букв просто, я просто не хочу правила которые делал кучу лет сливать для всех

Ну судя по ошибке у вас description отсутствует в перовом (нулевом) элементе из embeds. Вы точно не меняли название ключа description (может опечатка была)?

ну он называется content, который может быть description, я так понимаю Emded generator называет description content`ом

В общем смотрите: embeds.0.description означает, что есть ключ "embeds", по нему лежит список, 0 - нулевой элемент в этом списке, в нем должен быть (required) ключ "description". В вашем примере json ключ description в указанном месте есть. Теоретически этот json не должен вызывать эту ошибку. Ошибка никак не называет description контентом или что-то еще. Она пишет, что должен быть description.

я уже разобрался в ошибке и понял, что embeds.0.description не должен являться embed(убираем из json), но как дальше всё оформить(я немного тупой, и сам недопру как сделать так чтобы вместо embeds.0.description(который не embed, а просто сообщением будет) отправляло всё кроме него)
